# BizTalk/SQL Azure, transaction support via Elastic Database Transactions?

Tags: azure-sql-database, biztalk

We have a requirement that need to sync the data to SQL Azure instance. The feed now is running on BizTalk 2013 R2. We are wondering if we can leverage the out of box WCF-SQL adapter to push data to SQL Azure, but unsure the transaction support.

Any alternative solution if this cannot be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the WCF SQL Adapter or sqlBinding to connect to an Azure SQL database.

While there is no DTC, the fact is this combination is transactional enough to satisfy 99.99% of requirements.  Meaning, if there is an error in the database operation, you will get an error in the BizTalk app which you can handle.